# Is there a way to put some custom code in the header when using Elementor header template

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

Is there a way to put some custom code in the head of the page? Before Elementor you could do this by editing the header.php file of the template, but now, elementor eliminates all the code from the template, and there is no way (at least an obvious way) to do this. For me this is very important, because I like to put some tags in the code and also this is a perfect way to implement Google Analytics without using any other plugin. Google speed showing to add preload fonts because of speed. I also want to add Preload meta in header but don't want to use plugin. Please suggest better for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

as for google analytics the codes are javascript. you can easily add them into header using "HTML Widget" and then add the code between `script` tags.

and if you are looking for a way to add php codes, i recommend Dynamic.ooo. the plugin has a widget called "PHP Raw" which lets you write your php in elementor and put it anywhere you want. i myself currently use this plugin and it is a swiss army plugin!